# Which missions are on Disc 1 and which are on Disc 2?

Tags: mass-effect-3, xbox-360

If you're playing xbox 360 Mass Effect 3, you might find it infuriating *(as I do)* that at the beginning of the game is a chop of "INSERT DISC 1" and "INSERT DISC 2" depending on what order you choose missions...

I chose to do grissom academy mission (DISC 2) before going to do the missions regarding Krogan/Salarian. (DISC 1) and I did an N7 mission (DISC 2) before doing another Disc 1 mission..

**Does anyone have any idea what disc the missions are all supposed to be on?** Surely if you can complete them in any order you shouldnt be switching discs. They got Mass Effect 2 right, anyone know whats up with this one?

Comment: I didn't have to switch discs. I'm On the second level on disc two

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very similar to the way it worked in Mass Effect 2. Disc 1 contains the first and last missions of the game, while Disc 2 contains the more open middle part. However, as you experienced, some of the early side missions on Disc 2 are accessible while you're still on the Disc 1 part, but this isn't a big deal. Once you get to the Disc 2 part, there is no more disc swapping until you get to the final missions on Disc 1.

Comment: Disc 1 contained the ending on ME2?
I don't remember that.

Comment: @mike1987: It does. Once you enter the Omega-4 relay, you have to change back to Disc 1. It makes a lot of sense, really. Since the beginning and ending are the most linear parts of the game, having those on one disc and everything else on the other minimizes the number of disc changes. They were obviously trying to do the same for ME3, but I suspect they ran out of space and had to put a couple more missions on Disc 1, leading to some extra disc changes.

Comment: I don't remember going back to Disc 1 on ME2, Must not have felt a significant thing. This time it annoyed me because of the constant changing though.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful about swapping disks because some missions are time sensitive. If you complete the Krogan / Salarian (DISC 1) missions before moving to DISC 2, you will miss out on the Grissom Academy mission.

That being said, DISC 1 contains at least the start and ending:

> Start: Earth, Mars
>  End: Cerberus, Earth, Citadel

Comment: It had me move to Disc 2 for Grissom Academy.. And an N7 Mission, then back to Disc 1 for Korgan/Salarian mission.
But yeah, I know Disc 1 contains the ending and the start, But I don't understand why I'm being asked to switch discs this time around.
I'm doing missions in a different order this time, I actually missed Grissom Academy last time. But being asked to switch this often seems ridiculous. I can't work out where they went wrong with it.

Comment: @mike1987 sometimes people make poor design decisions.

Answer (score -1):

[According to Eurogamer](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/digitalfoundry-mass-effect-3-face-off), disc 1 contains all the core story mission (Priority:< something >), disc 2 contains the rest (all the N7 missions, etc).

Comment: Really? Must be annoying on 360...

Comment: Which is why I haven't turned mine on in ages and played ME3 on PC instead :p

Comment: I avoid the problem with my PS3 :). My laptop is too slow for new games

Comment: That's not the case Beth because I'm currently most of the priority stuff on disc 2.

Comment: Did you perhaps install disc 1 to HDD ? If not, that means the Digital Foundry article I linked is wrong, which is unusual !